# Select latest phase of objects not marked "remove"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in a PostgreSQL DB (simplified for the question), where I want to select only the rows marked with *:

```
uuid | status | info1 | info2
-------------------------------
1234 |   CONF |     - | 10
1234 |  START |   abc | 10
1234 |    FIN |   abc | 10 *
-------------------------------
7890 |   CONF |     - | 20 *
-------------------------------
1111 |   CONF |     - | 30
1111 |  START |   zzz | 30
1111 |    FIN |   zzz | 30
1111 |    REM |   zzz | 30
-------------------------------
2222 |   CONF |     - | 100
2222 |  START |   ijk | 100 *
```

The separating lines between different values of **uuid** are only for clarity, as I will explain now.

The logic for selection is the following:

- Partition the table by the column *uuid* in order to create *groups* of all the different values.
- Discard all the groups where there is at least one row with status **REM**.
- For all the remaining groups, select only the one with the last *status*. The values of this column define a custom order like this: CONF < START < FIN. The value *REM* is only used to *remove* this group of the selection.

I wrote this query that does the job, but I think there might be a better solution, and I have the sensation of abusing the subtable structures:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(numericphase.phase) OVER (PARTITION BY numericphase.uuid) AS s
    , *
    FROM(
        SELECT
         CASE
                WHEN status = 'FIN' THEN 3
                WHEN status = 'START' THEN 2
                WHEN status = 'CONF' THEN 1
                ELSE -1
            END AS phase
        , *
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            , BOOL_OR(status = 'REM')
            OVER (PARTITION BY uuid) AS removed
            FROM mytable
        ) nonremoved
        WHERE NOT removed
    ) numericphase
) lastphase
WHERE s = phase
AND s > 0
```

Here I'm doing the following operations (from inner to outer):

- First, select all rows where status is not `REM` (using `BOOL_OR`).
- Then, map each status value to a numeric one so they can be sorted.
- Compute the maximum value of each uuid group (corresponding to the last status following the custom sorting).
- Finally, select only rows where `status = max(status)`. This way, only the rows corresponding to the maximum status for each group are selected.

Any possible status that does not correspond to any value in this question is not suitable, so they are mapped to `-1` and discarded.

I think is easier to understand the problem by looking at the table than trying to redact it, so feel free to correct me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my edit of the question, I came to the following solution, which I think could be better optimized, but does the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    , MAX(numericphase.phase) OVER (PARTITION BY numericphase.uuid) AS s
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        , CASE
            WHEN status = 'REM' THEN 4
            WHEN status = 'FIN' THEN 3
            WHEN status = 'START' THEN 2
            WHEN status = 'CONF' THEN 1
            ELSE -1
        END AS phase
        FROM mytable
    ) numericphase
) lastphase
WHERE phase != 4
AND s = phase
AND s > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this (and it can now be removed from the question, where it doesn't really fit).  You could improve the value of this answer by actually reviewing the code and showing *how* this replacement improves on it.  We value self-answers; it does help if they reach the same standards of explanation as other answers.